# FileBrowser with JPanel Scrollable

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm trying to show a bunch of images in a panel. That panel would have a fix-size and will be scrollable to display all the pictures, a kind of thumbnail gallery. In fact, I don't understand how the `JScrollPanel` work with a `JPanel` and others. Could someone help to get a `JPanel` scrollable like a Windows Explorer? A panel containing components and scrollable.

I have a FlowLayoutPanel which extends JPanel
...

```
  public FlowLayoutPanel () 
  {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      this.setSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
  }
```

...

Now, I can add images to that panel ! But when the JPanel gets filled at is max (Maximum size), I would like to see a beautiful scrollbar on the right to just scroll through my Panel !

Comment: Can you post the code that you've used in your attempt to get it working?

Comment: Sure we can help you, but first you'll need to ask an answerable question. Right now your question is somewhat vague and very broad, and about the best anyone can do is to suggest that you read the JScrollPane tutorial (which you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)).

Comment: 1) Don't extend `JPanel` instead create a panel and set a layout.  2) Don't call `setSize()` but `setPreferredSize()`

Comment: But my goal here, is to create a FileExplorer as a CustomComponent. So I could take it from the Palette and drag it to my JFrame. So the base of my fileexplorer would have been an extended JPanel with a FlowLayout so the files could be placed one after the other left to right..just like in explorer ! Why wouldn't it be a good idea to extend a JPanel ? I'd like to remember y'all that I'm new to JAVA and swing components. I still don't understand the UI hierarchy very good !

Comment: Before trying to create custom components, first you need to learn Swing. For that you should put aside the GUI-builder for a bit and learn to create Swing by hand using the tutorials as a guide. You won't regret doing this.

Comment: Alright, it's a good idea..I've already started..and almost finished ! In C#, i've build many many robust custom components, here I'm just trying to figure out how to use a vertical scrollbar ! It shouldn't be that hard.. isn't it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to show a bunch of images in a panel

Maybe you can use a JList. It supports automatically wrapping when `horizontal wrap` is turned on.

> I would like to see a beautiful scrollbar on the right to just scroll through my Panel !

Then you need a custom layout manager, not a custom panel. See [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost -- Don't set the size of that JPanel. Let the layout managers decide on what the size should be. What you'll want to do is to create a new JScrollPane and pass this panel into the JScrollPane's constructor. Then you'll want to set the `preferredSize` of the JScrollPane or its viewport (as most layout managers respect the preferredSize, not the size).

Comment: Alright, seems good..so If I want to do a mini file explorer..Would it be a great idea to Extend a JScrollPane 
 then add a field CustomFLowLayoutPanel. I'd have a Custom Component extending JScrollPane, so I would just have to drag it to my JFrame ? Do you think it could work ?

Comment: +1 for spotting setSize vs. setPrefSize, -1 for setPrefSize - zero in sum <g>